# My Field Calculator Code has gone mad

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, field-calculator

I have been using the same code for my field calculator for the last 7 years.

However 2 days ago it is giving a strange result.

The code is for changing a String number to Text.
1000 into 1 + 000 or 3000 into 3 + 000 or 5230 into 5 + 230
But now it makes a code 1 + 1000 or 3 + 1000.
Very Strange. See attached image.

```
INT( [ET_STATION] /1000) & " + " & ROUND(((([ET_STATION] /1000) - INT( [ET_STATION] /1000))*1000),0)
```

I can not work out why it is doing this.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A friend reached out to me and wrote a new code in Python for me. For me before I always left it as VB with the other code. Thanks for the post BERA.

```
str(int(!ET_STATION!/1000))+" + " + str(int(round((((!ET_STATION!/1000) - int(int(!ET_STATION!)/1000))*1000),1)))
```